# Is this a good at-home exercise routine for a beginner?

Tags: workout-routines, stretching

I was recently handed this book on stretching exercises by my friend. It has a set of exercises that one is supposed to do daily; starting with 7 repetitions and gradually increasing to 9, 11 and so on till one can do 25 reps.

The exercise routine begins with a warm up consisting of:

Simple skipping for 3 minutes

Spot jogging for 3 minutes

20 - 25 jumping jacks

Once done with this, there are the below mentioned exercises:

**Two-arm stretch:** Raise both arms above your head. Breathe in, stretch as high as you can. Hold for 5 counts. Slacken as you breathe out.

**One-arm stretch:** Raise one arm above the head. Breathe in. Hold for count of 5. Slacken as you breathe out.

**Toe-touching:** Feet together. Bend down and touch your toes. Repeat 20 - 25 times.

**The Pelvic Tilt:** [This image shows it better](http://www.recreation.ubc.ca/files/2013/11/pelvic_tilt.jpg)

**Upward hand clasp:** Both the feet one foot apart. Hands raised above the head, clasp the fingers together. Bend to the left, straighten, bend to the right. breathe in when bending.

**Shoulder Shrugs:** [This image shows it better](http://www.setonspineandscoliosis.com/assets/images/exercise/neck_shrugs.jpg)

**Lying down hamstring stretch:** Lie down flat, hands off to the side. Raise legs to 90 degree with body. Stretch along the thighs as much as you can. Kinda like splits.

**Heel Raise:** [This image shows it better](http://www.abc.net.au/health/features/img/heelraises.gif) but I have to do one heel at a time.

**Strap assisted stretch:** Hang from some hooks for 3 minutes, increasing as you go on.

So I have the following few questions:
**1.** Is the **Pelvic Tilt** 'safe' ? How does it affect the spine ?
**2.** The same with the **Heel Raise**. The book says that it changes the arch of the foot. Both these exercises make me concerned because they actually 'change' the structure of the body and I am a first-timer exercising so I do not wanna do anything stupid.
**3.**  I do not get to do the last exercise as I do not have hooks to suspend myself from. Will it have a detrimental effect ?

I am 19, male.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The pelvic tilt and heel raise should be safe unless you have a specific problem that prevents you from doing them without discomfort. You may also want to check this [q/a](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/stretching-posture-exercise-for-separating-vertebrae-in-spine) for good exercises for desk work. It includes a link to a posture question that addresses muscles that tighten up with prolonged sitting.

Comment: Are you trying to lose weight, build muscle, become overall more flexible, or, etc....?

Comment: @Steven I am trying to just put all my muscles to use, actually. I am a software dev and most of my work is just sitting in front of a computer which is not healthy. This is an old question, though. I have joined a gym. However, I hope this will serve is a good starting point for people. :)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had problem with calf "heel" raises before, but I would take the writer's advice, calf raises are not my expertise. I do not know of whether pelvic tilts are safe or not, they didn't look extremely unsafe to me but it looked like it could possibly cause strain on certain areas(lower back, hip, etc.).

Overall, instead of answering your third question, I think I will recommend a new beginner workout program, such as this, because even though stretching is great, it won't build muscles and I believe does not burn much calories either. Here is a better program:

- 15-30 push ups a day, whenever you want.
- 40 crunches a day, whenever you want.
- 3-8 chin ups a day, whenever you want.
- Plank. 45 seconds.
- Wall Sit. 1 min.
- 40-50 bodyweight squats, anytime in the day.

I really believe this is a better program, but if you disagree, to answer the third question, yes, it would be detrimental, because hanging is one of, if not, the only exercise here that would build some muscle, mainly in your hands and forearms. I hope this enlightens you.

Answer (score -2):

According to me it's a good to begin exercise from home.

But you have the some things remember,

1) once visit the gym and get the idea of exercise..
2) If you want to loss weight then do only light exercise..
   Not heavy like dumbles, push up, sheet ups...
3) If you want to build body then you have to purchase dumbles, cardio, and extra equipment for long time.

4) Start first worm up excercises, jogging, straching, cycling.

All the Best

Comment: This answer is written poorly without sufficient detail