# Does it damage the joints if we do pushups everyday?

Tags: muscle, push-ups, muscle-gain

I'm doing 100 pushups everyday and now I'm afraid whether this will cause damage to the shoulder joints?
Will this help me to gain Chest muscles?

Thanks

Comment: IF you want to get bigger muscles, you should have a diet and training plan tailored to gaining mass. 100 pushups isnt the best way to gain muscle mass - please try searching for weight gaining and muscle mass questions on this site.

Comment: maybe, but any serious athletic activity has the *potential* to cause injury.  its important to "listen to your body" - if you start feeling pain in your shoulder joint, take it as a sign to back off the exercise, make sure you have good form, possibly increase the level of difficulty more slowly

Comment: Watch your form. If you flare your elbows out at 90 degrees, it will likely cause problems eventually. Better to keep them tucked in close to your side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeking two answers here:

1. Will you have shoulder problems if you continue to perform 100 push-ups everyday?  The answer is it depends.  If you have been doing 100 push-ups everyday, and you haven't had any shoulder problems, then you probably won't have a shoulder problem in the short run. However, you might want to consider [pec stretches](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11837/proper-way-to-stretch-the-pectoral-muscles/11843#11843) and some back exercises to prevent a potential shoulder problem in the long run.  This common problem in the long run is called shoulder impingement due to muscular imbalances (from your push-ups - strengthening the front - chest and shoulders, but no strengthening the back muscles - so add chin-ups and [rows](http://www.getfitchimp.com/exercise/seated-cable-row) when you do your push-ups from now on).
2. Will doing 100 push-ups everyday help you gain chest muscles?  The answer for this question is also depending on your goals.  If your goal is to continue to improve muscular endurance, then you have to continue to increase the load by doing higher reps (ie. long distance runners).  However, if your goal is to increase muscle size, then you have to follow the progressive overload principle by increasing the load to your chest muscles by picking weights/exercises that you can only perform around 8-15 reps with proper rest (every other day).  This can be done with variations ([decline push-ups](http://www.getfitchimp.com/exercise/decline-push-up), [plyo push-ups](http://www.getfitchimp.com/exercise/plyo-push-up) or [clap push-ups](http://www.getfitchimp.com/exercise/clap-push-up) or [weighted push-ups](http://www.getfitchimp.com/exercise/weighted-push-up)).

Your muscles till get used to a certain load and movement pattern after a while (4-6 weeks) based upon the neuromuscular adaptation principle.  So, you have to continue to challenge your muscles whether your goal is to improve muscular endurance or increasing muscle size.  And of course, proper nutrition is vital for either goal.

Hope this answer is helpful!