# Exercises for loosening up back muscles

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, dumbbells, back-pain

I spend most my time sitting in front of my computer, so my back often feels tight and sometimes my upper back muscles between the shoulder blades are really hurting.

So I'm looking for some exercises to specifically target that area of my back, not to build the muscles but to loosen it up and have good health in those areas.

I don't have access to a gym so I can only do bodyweight and dumbbell.

I already have a pretty normal routine with pushups, cardio and various sit up and dumbbell exercises, but am looking for something specific for my back.

Comment: See [Exercises for Posture](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do) that specifically target the upper back and shoulder blades as well as other muscles that are affected by prolonged sitting.

Comment: You need more yoga than exercises. I would look in that direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When my shoulders are tight from too much computering, I make sure to warm up and do some arm circles (3 sets of 8-10 forward and back each side), a lot of dead hangs from a pull-up bar, should shoulder dislocates with a stick. Pull-ups are also good, since they strengthen the back muscles, helping to prevent a forward hunch. Yoga, particularly down dog, is also helpful for improving the range of motion for my arms overhead.