# Exercises to correct bad shoulder posture

Tags: posture, back

My shoulder posture is somehow incorrect. My shoulders and neck are leaned forward and scapulae are pointing out. I think that the shoulders are also a little rotated forward.

I think some of my muscles are shortened because I can't achieve correct posture even when I'm trying.

Can you recommend me some gym exercises or stretching exercises which will help me to correct the posture of the shoulders and whole upper back in general?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You may want to check some of these [exercises for posture](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do). The "wall pec stretch" is effective. However, you can't really just correct part of your posture without addressing your whole body. The forward shoulders and neck may be coming from tightness in your legs, pelvis or trunk.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called as horizontal shrugs; which can be seen in this link;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3cupvX9mv4

This can also be conducted while lying on a bench too. It is a great exercise, and you don't need much weight to do it. Instead, try to go for high reps, such as 10-20; and hold that weight for a little moment at the top (like 1 full seconds).

Good luck. Stay strong.