# Taping the back for good posture

Tags: posture

Is it true that simple duct tape can be used to correct bad posture? If so can someone suggest how to do this and is there something better than duct tape (something water proof, for instance) available for this?

Comment: You mean *wrapping a duct tape around your core?*

Comment: While taping or strapping may be a temporary help, [correcting your posture using exercise](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do/7015#7015) is better for the long term.

Comment: This is not related to physical fitness and is off topic for the site.

Comment: @JohnP - really? You see posture as unrelated to fitness? Perhaps if you have some more wisdom to shed on this topic it would be appreciated.

Comment: @TVMohini - We expect questions about such things as posture to be *related to an ongoing fitness program*. Simply saying "I have bad posture, how do I correct it?" is general medical advice and off topic. It needs to be related to your own fitness program and what the impact of bad posture is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go with duct tape, as that would most likely hurt when you remove it. ;)
Kinesio tape is generally used to help support injured areas.

I think it would be better to go this route:  http://myfiveminuteyoga.com/303/take-your-shoulders-back-with-a-long-strap/

[image]

**Reasons:**

1. It's not duct tape, so no skin tearing and no adhesive
2. It's reusable
3. It's adjustable *after* you put it on, which duct tape isn't.  (Do you really want to realize that you made it too tight, take it off, then have to do it over again?)

From personal experience, the yoga strap is surprisingly comfortable.