# Help with my posture please?

Tags: posture

My posture is really bad. I believe that I have upper-cross syndrome. (I think that is what it's called?)

I have searching the web and YouTube but nothing seems to help with my posture. When I do try to sit or stand up straight my back gets sore after a bit. I went to jump america and after about 30 min my back just starts hurting I am not sure if it is about my posture but I'm just saying maybe you guys know something. My bad posture may be giving me really bad headaches and again I am not sure if it is because of my terrible posture.

If you know something that will help tell me? Thanks.

Comment: A picture of your posture should be pretty much mandatory here.

Comment: It looks like you have weak back muscles but without a diagnosis It is hard to tell. It can also be related to other medical problems (kyphosis scoliosis and lordosis). It is best for you to see your physician. You can try asking this question on health SE or Admins can also move the question over there for you. See the link below: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do?rq=1

Comment: If it is appropriate admins will move, please don't crosspost. And in the current form it would be closed on health too, as it is a "diagnose me" question.