# Disengaged muscles in back of the neck

Tags: neck

The back of my neck feels sore at one side sometimes after a long day working in front of the computer. Somehow it improves by massaging the proper spot and by stretching.

It's like the muscles were disengaged, but not injured since it can improve rapidly by the proper actions.

I want to know what's the official name of this and whether muscle exercises, would help prevent it from happening.

Comment: These may be of some help to you: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do,  http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 0):

It **could** be Cervicalgia but only a doctor will be able to tell you what it really is.

Neck pain can be caused by a lot of things.. But they are 2 populars reasons :

- Stress
- Position

You should go see an osteopath/chiro, they will help a lot. You can also ask them how to exercise your back/neck at home.

You could also look on amazon for a corset to maintain your back right when you're sit. Cheap one are very bad.

Answer (score 0):

In grad school I did a study on the Postural Effects of Pain -- so I love these questions.

There is so much going back there I don't have nearly enough info to give you an answer (there is no way to give any rational diagnosis with what is currently known)

- What side is sore?  The side your bending towards or opposite side?
- What type of pain (burning dull etc) and where exactly do you feel
  it?
- How long has this been happening?
- Besides massaging -- does anything else decrease or increase the pain?
- What movements make the pain worse or better?

Let me know if you'd like help.

Comment: Again - we are not a discussion forum. Questions are expected to have answers, not a further list of questions.