# Sore glutes from running

Tags: running, recovery, muscle-recovery, glutes

General question: why would the upper glute area (piriformis, gluteus minimus, gluteus medius) get disproportionately tight and sore from running?

For me, the tightness and soreness in this specific region seems out of proportion to other areas of my body. Nothing else gets this sore or tight.

This area gets sore enough that it is the limiting factor in my recovery from longer runs. Following a long run, typically the rest of my body is ready to go again on schedule, while this area has yet to recover completely.

Info specific to me: I am not currently doing weight training, but I think my strength is fairly balanced across all the muscle groups involved in running. My glutes have genetic capacity to be one of my stronger body parts; this area has never been my weak area.

I am interested in improving my running technique, training methods, mobility or whatever else is required so that I do not over-stress these muscles.

If more info is needed, please leave a comment and I'll update the question.

**UPDATE:**

- I have no numbness.
- My soreness is normal delayed onset muscle soreness. I would not say I have pain other than DOMS.
- I have no symptoms of nerve compression.
- I do have tightness immediately after running.

**Response to Mike-DHSc**

I think you are generally on the right track. I sit a lot, and my sitting posture is not great. I would not be surprised if my hip abductors are lengthened. My hip flexors are shorted, and I have been working on that through Dr. Kelly Starrett's mobility program for a few months (and getting good results). But I have not been addressing lengthened hip abductors. What do you recommend (given that I'm already doing all the stretches you recommended)?

**Final Update**
I implemented some hip abductor strengthening exercises and continued the mobility work and the issue has almost entirely gone away.

Comment: Fantastic question btw - forgot to add that.

Comment: Great job --  way to stay consistent and glad things worked out well for you!  If any other questions come up just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pain and numbness ***always*** results from either blood vessel or nerve compression /restriction.

You’re describing a classic presentation - movement followed by tight musculature along with pain & numbness.

Based on the region the majority of these cases are related to a tight Piriformis.

> **Why not the Glutes?**

Typically, your hip abductors (Glute Min / Med) are weak or lengthened [Jaunda’s Upper and Lower Crossed Syndrome](http://www.jandaapproach.com/the-janda-approach/jandas-syndromes/)

As the pain is located in the upper gluteal area - the glutes are rarely implicated as you’d likely see pain laterally.  This would also commonly present as lateral knee soreness or hip snapping (during movement).

See the image below it shows the vessels that pass exactly where you’re describing.  As the sciatic nerve actually pierces the Piriformis muscle in 15% of the population.

[image]

[Free 3D Anatomy Model](https://human.biodigital.com/index.html)

---

Symptoms are very similar to **Piriformis Syndrome** or **SI Joint Dysfunction**.  There are a ton of secondary causes that could exacerbate this *(spinal pathology, an innominate torsion, stenosis, weak abdominals etc.)*.

Below I posted some great exercises aimed at alleviating this found at [spine-health.com](http://spine-health.com/)

---

### Supine Piriformis Stretches

*(Three Different Stretches)*

---

1. Lie on the back with the legs flat. Pull the affected leg up toward 
   the chest, holding the knee with the hand on the same side of thebody and grasping the ankle with the other hand. Trying to lead with
   the ankle, pull the knee towards the opposite ankle until stretch is
   felt. Do not force ankle or knee beyond stretch. Hold stretch for 30
   seconds, then slowly return to starting position. Aim to complete a
   set of three stretches.

---

2. Lie on the floor with the legs flat. Raise the affected leg and place
   that foot on the floor outside the opposite knee. Pull the knee of
   the bent leg directly across the midline of the body using the
   opposite hand or a towel, if needed until stretch is felt. Do not
   force knee beyond stretch or to the floor. Hold stretch for 30
   seconds, then slowly return to starting position. Aim to complete a
   set of three stretches.

---

3. Lie on the floor with the affected leg crossed over the other leg at
   the knees and both legs bent. Gently pull the lower knee up towards
   the shoulder on the same side of the body until stretch is felt. Hold
   stretch for 30 seconds, then slowly return to starting position. Aim
   to complete a set of three stretches.

---

### Buttocks Stretch for the Piriformis

- Begin on all fours. Place the affected foot across and underneath the
  trunk of the body so that the affected knee is outside the trunk.
  Extend the non-affected leg straight back behind the trunk and keep
  the pelvis straight. Keeping the affected leg in place, scoot the
  hips backwards towards the floor and lean forward on the forearms
  until deep stretch is felt. Do not force your body to floor. Hold stretch
  for 30 seconds, then slowly return to starting position. Aim to
  complete a set of three stretches.

**Single Knee to Chest Stretch.**

- Pull one knee up to the chest at a time, gently pumping the knee
  three to four times at the top of the range of motion. Do 10
  repetitions for each leg. Press-up. From the prone position, press up
  on the hands while the pelvis remains in contact with the floor. Keep
  the lower back and buttocks relaxed for a gentle stretch.  Hold the
  press-up position initially for five seconds, and gradually work up
  to 30 seconds per repetition. Aim to complete 10 repetitions.

---

### UPDATE

Thanks for the additional info – love trying to make sense of what’s going on.

I work PRN as a PT so I can run it by coworkers if needed but obviously would need a full eval to get a proper Dx.

***A couple questions:***

1. Is this pain unilateral or bilateral?
2. When exactly does the pain first occur (are you just tight after a
   run or is there pain as well)?
3. When is the pain most intense?  How long before it goes away?
4. When did you first notice this (sudden onset or gradual)?
5. Once sore, any specific movement(s) make the pain worse or better?
6. Have you recently changed your program in anyway (distance,
   intensity, mode etc.)?
7. Have you even had any kind of movement screen done?  Such as the
   FMS, SFMS etc.. https://www.functionalmovement.com/system/home

**See this:**
http://www.irunfar.com/2016/04/if-you-cant-do-this-exercise-you-will-get-hurt-hip-stability-and-alignment-for-trail-runners.html

---

Possibly hip and altered neuromuscular firing patterns.
I’ll wait to go any further till I have more info.

---

Comment: I have no numbness. And my pain is normal delayed onset muscle soreness. I have no symptoms of nerve compression. But there is tightness immediately after running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been following Dr. Kelly Starrett's MobilityWOD program for a few months. I'm doing a lot of mobility work that targets this area. Another of my favorites is the yoga pigeon pose. I do about 1 hour of mobility work per day now (starting a few months ago).

Comment: please see my updated question with answers to your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I started by assuming your suggestions were correct. I implemented strengthening exercises for the upper glutes. Result: after just one week there is already a noticeable improvement. So it looks like your analysis was on the mark. Thanks

Comment: Very happy to hear things are working out for you!  I was hesitant to update this further as probing questions and detailed advice from a licensed medical professional or otherwise seems very unwelcome here. My answers have been deleted, closed etc.  Gets somewhat frustrating as I am simply trying to help. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/33013/disengaged-muscles-in-back-of-the-neck/34359?noredirect=1#comment55149_34359

Comment: I'm glad you decided to help me. BTW, the most telling thing I have discovered since your answer is that on side planks with upper leg raised (supporting weight only with lower leg), my right side is significantly weaker than my left. That is reflected in the fact that my right side gets more sore than my left. I'm sure that my mobility work combined with the new strengthening work (and a focus on strengthening the right side) will resolve the issue for me.