# Really Bad posture now hurting me whats the best solution?

Tags: posture, back

Hi i am 17 year old and have been using computers since age of 11. I had bit lower back pains but never bothered to inquire about it. I have sat most of my life and now i am 17 since 2 years my back strength is too weak i cant even stand erected for long time i have to lie down or sit. My weight has also increased and problems have become worse. Daily in morning my shoulder neck and back is paining at least for fifteen minutes and my chest feels short of breath. My posture has become very odd (I have added pictures). This is indirectly affecting my work and studies a lot my self confidence has also decreased. I need proper guidance for improving my posture and strengthening my back. Thanks for help in advance. I really appreciate everyone's help.   [image: My back posture right now.]

Comment: Also see https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do/7015#7015

Answer (score 3):

We can't provide a full life-routine for you to follow, as we'd need to diagnose a lot more than what we can see in the picture, and the paragraph you wrote. But I'll touch on the most immediate pitfall I see, and provide some further learning resources.

After that, it's up to you to seek out a qualified physician, or a physical therapist to help you.

**The anterior pelvic tilt**

When we sit a lot - and I mean a LOT - our [hip flexors](http://www.sports-injury-info.com/image-files/hip-pain-hip-flexor.jpg) will do what's called "adaptive shortening". Essentially, they realize that in the seated posture, they don't have much room, and they get sort of squished together, and the react by making themselves shorter to avoid the tension.

This causes the anterior pelvic tilt, where the front of your pelvis is pulled down, which pushes your rear upward. This, in turn, can very quickly cause lower back pain because it's like a big pinch.

More info and guidance:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-CrEi0ymMg
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1sfPfsESDQ

Note: The guy in this video is very well educated in anatomy, physical therapy and personal training, and in this way he separates himself from most of the fitness gurus of YouTube. In fact, I advise you to scroll though his entire library, and watch any video that applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

As Alec mentioned, it's anterior pelvic tilt and it's a common result of our sit-on-butt lifestyle. It takes a long time to develop, and it will take a long time to resolve fully. Some general notes I would make:

- Don't just start "lifting weights", follow [a proper strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091).
- Don't fall victim to the "1 & 23 problem" whereby you spend one hour a day exercising and the rest sitting down or laying down.

You need to build strength (via [a proper program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091)) and change your lifestyle. Instead of sitting down, get a stand up desk. Go walking for lunch, ride your bike or walk to something instead of driving, and basically try to get out of the seated position as often as you can.

Your body will adapt to whatever you throw at it. Start providing it stimulus it needs in order to get stronger and healthier.