# Best way to fix rounding shoulders?

Tags: exercise, shoulders, posture

I recently started a programming job and have notice my shoulders have started to round. I try to sit with good posture but my posture breaks after a certain time and I don't notice it.

I workout 5 times a week and follow a good workout plan (includes all compound lifts). Whats some good workout or stretches I can add to fix rounding shoulders?

Comment: See if this helps: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do