# Workout to fix kyphosis/neck

Tags: back, posture, mobility

This has been loosely answered before, but when I look this up online, I get a mix between exercises made for a 70 year old senior to improve shoulder mobility, and other articles that have a big enough difference in terms of fixing posture, or a list of 20+ exercises to do. I use to have lordosis, kyphosis, and neck lordosis("s back"). I was able to better my kyphosis and fix my lordosis. Since working from home started and due to a newborn baby, my kyphosis is back and worse than before. I'd like some workout exercises that I can realistically include into a muscle/strength routine.. I have time for a few mobility drills and stretches but I cant dedicate my entire workout to doing kyphosis recovery. Is there a workout plan I can do to fix these? for instance, using barbells for middle traps, etc.. rather than simply raising my arms up on a bench.. or does anyone know a solid fix that's worked for them before?

Comment: Make sure you are doing a lot more horizontal pulling: rows, face pulls and overhead trap pulls than pushing. "Stop" benching. Mobility drills and stretches are less important. For more details see my answer to this question: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/42490/what-activities-are-good-for-your-posture/42498#42498.

Comment: Your answer on the other post pretty much answered everything. I hate doing the grandma stretches. so weight training is nice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strength training is an excellent way to fix postural issues like thoracic kyphosis.  I've read of many people who alleviated their kyphosis through barbell training specifically.  It's especially common among elderly trainees.  Assuming your spinal anatomy is otherwise normal, you should be able to improve your posture by strengthening your back, hips, and abs.

I would recommend doing the main barbell lifts - squat, deadlift, press, and bench.  And I would recommend following a barbell training program, specifically a novice linear progression.

As your back and abs strengthen, it will become easier to hold your thoracic spine with a normal amount of flexion.  When performing the lifts, you will have to make a conscious effort to hold your thoracic spine in as extended a position as you can muster (not into actual extension, but rather normal flexion at most), but over time, this should get easier.  And as your hips, abs, and back strengthen, it will become easier to hold your lumbar spine with a normal amount of extension.